# Flutter Firestore where clause using map

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When a new activity is posted i add a new post document into the collection.
Inside this document i have a map where users add confirmation to the event marking it as true and adding his own id.

[image: Firestore Screen]

```
var snap = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('user_posts')        
        .where("confirmations.${user.id}",isEqualTo: true)
        .getDocuments();
```

With this snippet i'm able to get all the posts confirmed by the user. The issue here is to get this a index is required to perform this query. And this index can't be generic. I can't create a index for each user.

Some idea of how to get it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to turn the `confirmations` field into an array, and use the (relatively recent) `array-contains` and `arrayUnion` operations.

The equivalent query with an array like that would become:

```
var snap = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('user_posts')        
    .where("confirmations", arrayContains: user.id)
    .getDocuments();
```

And this way you only need an index on `confirmations`, which is added automatically.

For more on these see:

- the [blog post introducing these operations](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html)
- the [documentation on updating arrays](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)
- the [documentation on array membership queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership)