# how to get sub colleciton data if exist from root collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

From firstore how to get subcollection data if exist in the root collection. Here is my collection structure.

```
A(collection)
    Doc1(document)--->types(collection)------100
                                       ------200
                                       ------300
    Dco2(Document)
```

A is root collection,  and it has many document, but some document in root collection(A) can contain sub collection. Hence I want get sub collection data if exist.

Am using **angularfire5 and angular8** to implement this functionality

Please help me on this.

Comment: Just query the subcollection.  You don't have to check if it exists.  If it doesn't exist, then your query will simply get no documents back.

Comment: Problem is colleciton name is unknow to I. And I want to combine all root collection data into on list and display it in dropdown

Comment: If you don't know the name of a collection, you can't query it.  You also can't use a client SDK to list names of subcollections.  Consider restructuring your data so that you always know the names of collections that have the data you need.

Comment: I mean, Root collection A document(doc1, doc2, doc3) can have different sub collection like X, Y and Z. So in order to get X, Y and Z sub collection dynamically, I cannot hard code right. Because i will be running a loop to get root collection A data

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments - and as can be check in this other question from the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092897/creating-listview-with-getting-data-from-firestore-on-flutter/61097140?noredirect=1#comment108097776_61097140) - it's not possible to perform queries, when you don't have the name of the collection. If you would like to query the subcollections, you would need their names as well.

For this reason, it will be needed for you to either change your database and application, to have pre-defined names for the collections, so you always know the names of them.