# How can I know if my QuerySnapshot have some register? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            title: AppAbar(),
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: FlexibleAppBar(),
            ),
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0,),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                List.generate(6, (idx) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                      elevation: 3,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      child: Consumer<TimeSheetRepository>(
                              builder: (BuildContext context, TimeSheetRepository db, Widget child) {
                                _queryWeekYear = db.queryByMonthYear(
                                    12, 2020);
                                return StreamBuilder(
                                    stream: _queryWeekYear,
                                    builder: (context, snapshot){
                                      if(!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.documents == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                      return ListTile(
                                        leading: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Text('${_numWeeks[idx]}'),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        title: Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/16,
                                          child: ListView.builder(
                                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                              itemCount: 7,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                return Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                                                  child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Row(
                                                          children: [
                                                            Column(
                                                              children: [
                                                                Text('${(DateFormat('EEEE').format(firstweek[index]).substring(0, 1))}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54)),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                            SizedBox(width: 28.0),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ]
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              }
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        subtitle: Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/20,
                                          child: ListView.builder(
                                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                                                return Column(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Row(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Column(
                                                            children: [
                                                              Text('${docSnapshot['date'].toString()}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54)),
                                                              **// HERE I'M TRYING TO PUT THE DATE (IF EXISTS IN MY QUERY) BUT I NEED PUT IT IN THE CORRECT DAY IN MY CARD**
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                          SizedBox(width: 28.0),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ]
                                                );
                                              }
                                          )
                                        ),
                                        trailing: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight.withOpacity(0.2),
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                              ),
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: Text( "148", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.shade800, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 18.0),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                }
                                );
                              }
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                })
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I built a card, inside I have a listview.buider making a days of the weeks, and I have my Stream with QuerySnapshot with some days. I'm trying to put in my widget day, the same day that I have in my QuerySnapshot.

How can I get a specify date from my query?

I did some changes, but doesn't works.

I need to find inside my QuerySnapshot if X day is there, if not continue next

Comment: try following this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092897/creating-listview-with-getting-data-from-firestore-on-flutter

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but I need to do this

I hay a Card with the days 
MON     TUS     WED    THU     FRI      SAT      SUN
DIC13  DIC14  DIC15  DCI16  DIC17  DIC18  DIC19

and in my QuerySnapshot I have many date, I trying to get the same date on my query.

Comment: @JoseO show a code on what you have so far.