# Querying Firestore map fields in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve posts in my Firestore database from a field called `"bookmarks"`. The field `"bookmarks"` is of type map. When a user bookmarks a post, the field is updated with the `deviceId` being set to `true` like this:

```
▼ bookmarks
     deviceId : true
```

When the post is unbookmarked, `deviceId : true`is deleted and the `bookmarks` field  remains empty like this:

`bookmarks: {}`

I am trying to retrieve posts from `"bookmarks"` where `deviceID` is set to `true`. My query however returns all posts including posts where `bookmarks` is empty.

This is my query :

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await postsRef
        .document(postId)
        .collection('users_posts')
        .where('bookmarks', arrayContains: deviceId)
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();
```

Please help figure out what I am doing wrong. Attatched is the structure of my database.
Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bookmarks` field is not an array, so you can't query it like an array.  It's a map, and you can query for the values of nested fields of a map using dot notation:

```
.where('bookmarks.${deviceId}', isEqualTo: true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
`.where('bookmarks.${deviceId}', isEqualTo: true)` returns an empty list even after enabling indexing. 
I also checked this post earlier before asking the question.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012380/flutter-firestore-where-clause-using-map]

Comment: ...Also on the Index menu of Fire of Cloud Firestore,we can add an Index but we cannot remove an index (not even by hovering as said by the documentation)...am i missing something?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson : in a query on a map with 10 nested fields where we check 10 times isEqualTo,  Firestore will create 1 index?...and if then we  query only 9 fields on this map , will it use the same index or create an additional one?...doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#index_entries "says you can reduce the number of indexes by taking advantage of Cloud Firestore's ability to merge indexes for equality clauses" but with no explanation

Answer (score 0):

I tried that notation but didn't work for me, here is the notation I used:
where("bookmarks.deviceId:true"), you can replace true with the value you are looking.