# Filtering stream from Cloud Firestore using map field

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Cloud Firestore collection called `chats` and their documents have the following structure:

[image]

Here you have another document from the same collection:

[image]

As you may seen, both documents have a common `users` item, in this case the common item is `modestovasco@gmail.com: null`, but on the first document the item is at first place and on the second item it is at second place.

I need to create a Stream that should filter the `chats` collection for documents which have a certain email at field `users` and should filter on both places, first and second.

In the current state, if I am looking for modestovasco@gmail.com, the filter should retrieve both documents.

Here you have my current code for the filter:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("chats")
                      .where('users', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: {usuario!.email: null})
                      .snapshots()
```

This stream is only getting the first document.

Comment: A key word to search for is `StreamTransformer` and maybe merge Streams. I am also "fighting" with this - without merging - so cannot help you more then telling you where to look

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrayContainsAny` method on where clause it will give you those documents where the given email is present on users field no matter on which place the email is present.

The modified code is given below:

```
final String emailTobeChecked = 'modestovasco@gmail.com';
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('chats')
  .where('users', arrayContainsAny: emailTobeChecked)
  .snapshots()
```

For more information you can [click here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying)

Comment: the field users is not an array, it is a map

Comment: @mvasco Apologies Removed the brackets a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54012655/20239914) was posted on this thread